# Dynamically inserted table: last row not detected by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery for creating dynamic table row based on user insertion.

My HTML:

```
     <table id="list">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>first header</th>
                <th>second header</th>
                <th>third header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" name="first" /></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="second" id="second" /></td>
                 <td><button class="alert hollow button" href="#">X</button>                 </td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
     </table>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$('#list tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]').keyup(function (event) {

    if ($(this).val().length > 4 && $('#list tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]').val().length > 4) {
        $('#list tbody').append('<tr>
                     <td><input type="text" name="first" /></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="second" id="second" /></td>
                     <td><button class="alert hollow button" href="#">X</button></td>
                   </tr>');
    }
});
```

The above code only works for the first row and the inserted row has no JS code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given complete code, but i suspect this is your issue..

Replace this

```
$('#list tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]').keyup(function (event)
```

with this

```
$('#list').on('keyup', 'tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]', function (event)
```

You are probably not using proper event delegation, and you're trying to bind a `keyup` event on an element that doesn't exist yet (you say the rows are added dynamically). Instead we bind the keyup to the table that is part of the initial document, and say what happends when a child that meets X criteria has a keyup event fired

Comment: When new elements will be added subsequently, do you think, this code will get binded to each new element and so in effect all rows will trigger this code while only the last one should do so?

Comment: The way i wrote the new line for you, you only need to call that "keyup" function once. That table will forever (unless you unbind the event) react to when a child that matches the 'tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]' selector fires a keyup event.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not bind to elements that don't exist on page load, use **`on`** for dynamically generated elements

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#list tr:last td:nth-last-child(2) input[name=second]', function (event) {
```